# How to get/update is_super_admin in the auth.users table

Tags: reactjs, authentication, supabase

I would like to use the `is_super_admin` column in the auth.users table. However, I cannot find any way to query its value in React.

I have tried both

```
supabase.auth.getUser()
```

and with service role enabled

```
supabaseAdmin.auth.admin.getUserById(user.id)
```

but both only give me the same user object without the `is_super_admin` value.

Is there a way to access `is_super_admin` value in the auth.users table?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to access is_super_admin value in the auth.users table?

No, there isn't. If you want to implement some kind of role based feature, you should do it through creating a public users table and store the information there.